# InspIRCd ssl connection fails with Cloudflare certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, irc, cloudflare

I am trying to implement SSL into my IRC server, I have downloaded and installed the certificate, key, and ca-bundle from Cloudflare. And I can connect successfully without SSL but when I do try to use it I get an error message stating: `Connection failed (unable to verify the first certificate.? (21))`. I'm not sure why the certificate can't be verified, and `openssl verify` results in an `OK` message.

My SSL config:

```
<gnutls cafile="/etc/inspircd/sslcerts/origin_ca_rsa_root.pem"
        certfile="/etc/inspircd/sslcerts/cloudflare.pem"
        keyfile="/etc/inspircd/sslcerts/cloudflare.key"
        priority="SECURE192:-VERS-SSL3.0">
<module name="m_ssl_gnutls.so">
```